# Is there a programmatic way to gather JIRA search term data for analysis?

Tags: jira

I would like to analyze the search terms submitted by our JIRA users so we can formalize best practices for creating subjects and descriptions.

I'd like to avoid having to pull the search terms out of log files, where I believe they live if the right log levels are set.

I am familiar with [jira-python](https://pythonhosted.org/jira/) and server-side JIRA customization, but this one's stumping me.

Is there a programmatic way to generate a list of the search terms submitted to JIRA? (Client-side/API is ideal, but server-side is okay too.)

Appreciate any advice folks can share, pointers to references, and so forth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for this, but you can get this information from the webserver logs or by looking at saved_searches directly in the database. Clearly these would be only the saved filters, not all queries performed.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. But thanks for validating!

Answer (score 0):

What about catching everything that is submitted to search field (client-side) and log it on server side (POST to servlet).

Comment: That would be an option if we wanted to track it ongoing for sure. Unfortunately, I don't have the opportunity  to customize the instance like that, unfortunately. Thanks for the idea, though!